# Change HTML button caption in "onclick" event

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my HTML for a button on a VERY simple page:

```
<button onclick="handleButton(this)" 
           name="buttonLeft"
           type="button" 
          class="myButton" 
              id="ButtonLeft">Toggle Left Garage</button>
    <br />Door is Secure</td>
```

In my `onclick` event handler (`handleButton()`), I want to change the caption from "Toggle Left Garage" to "Left Garage Toggled." Obviously, I want to do more, but I'm just debugging for now. Yet, I can't seem to figure out how to do this simple thing.

Should be as simple as

```js
function handleButton(element) 
{
  element.something="Left Garage Toggled";
}
```

### I tried `element.value`, and it doesn't seem to work.

OK, here's the actual code with no embelishment or spacing fixes....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type"
 content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Garage Doors</title>
  <style>
.myButton {
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #97c4fe;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #97c4fe;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #97c4fe;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #3d94f6), color-stop(1, #1e62d0));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #3d94f6 5%, #1e62d0 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3d94f6 5%, #1e62d0 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #3d94f6 5%, #1e62d0 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #3d94f6 5%, #1e62d0 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #3d94f6 5%, #1e62d0 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3d94f6', endColorstr='#1e62d0',GradientType=0);
background-color:#3d94f6;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
border:1px solid #337fed;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:19px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:6px 24px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #1570cd;
}
.myButton:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #1e62d0), color-stop(1, #3d94f6));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e62d0 5%, #3d94f6 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e62d0 5%, #3d94f6 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #1e62d0 5%, #3d94f6 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e62d0 5%, #3d94f6 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e62d0 5%, #3d94f6 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e62d0', endColorstr='#3d94f6',GradientType=0);
background-color:#1e62d0;
}
.myButton:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="text-align: center; width: 681px; height: 381px;"
 border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <button onclick="handleButton(this)" name="buttonLeft"
 type="button" class="myButton" id="ButtonLeft">Toggle
Left Garage</button>
      <br \="">
Door is Secure</td>
      <td>
      <button onclick="handleButton(this)" name="buttonRight"
 class="myButton">Toggle Right
Garage
Door
      </button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<script>
function handleButton(caller)
{
caller.innerHTML=caller.id;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, that didn't work. I can't even be sure the event handler is being called. How do you guys debug this stuff?

Comment: Open your console with F12 (usually F12) and check for errors. Also, use `console.log()` statements to output to the console.

Comment: I added the actual code taken directly from the editor (CompoZer). I used "handleButton(caller)" so I could use the same function for all the buttons.

Comment: Thank you for the console log tip. I didn't know it existed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, all for your help. It turns out that the preview browser in CompoZer is the problem. It doesn't appear to execute JS at all. I opened the underlying file in Chrome, and it worked perfectly (as amended by a couple of you....)

I thank you for your attention. I appreciate it beyond words.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to target the innerHTML.

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/grwovnyv/

Javascript

```
function handleButton(element) {
    element.innerHTML = "Left Garage Toggled";
}
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="handleButton(this)" name="buttonLeft" type="button" class="myButton" id="ButtonLeft">Toggle Left Garager</button>
<br/>Door is Secure
```

Also just a side note your HTML was a little bit screwy but I also fixed that in the jsFiddle

`(Thanks to RobG for pointing this out below)`

Or you can use textContent

```
function handleButton(element) {
    element.textContent = "Left Garage Toggled";
}
```

Comment: While *innerHTML* works, the *textContent* property is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to close your elements properly.
Try this..

```
<button onclick="handleButton()"
    name="buttonLeft"
    type="button"
    class="myButton"
    id="ButtonLeft">
    Toggle Left Garage
</button>
<br />
Door is Secure

<script>
    function handleButton()
    {
        document.getElementById('ButtonLeft').innerHTML = "Left Garage Toggled";
    }

</script>
```

Then if you want. Put the 'script' inside the .js file

Answer (score 0):

for the html I spot some mistakes! 
line 5 should look more like this:

```
id="buttonleft">Toggle Left Garage</button>
```